# Query a 3rd level nested

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

I have a DB in MongoDB that has 3 levels, and I want to get the value form last level. The structure is the following:

```
{
    "_id" : "10000",
    "Values" : [
        {
            "Value1" : "Article 1",
            "Value2" : [
                {
                    "Value2_1" : 1,
                    "Value2_2" : 2,
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to get the value form the label "Value2_1".

So far my code is the following:

```
for row in collection.find({"_id":1, "Values.Value2.Value2_1":1})
     print(row)
```

The output is always "None".

Any ideas about how to make the correct query?

Thanks!

Comment: Values[0] I assume as the first values is a list, same for Value2 if you are going to use it and are sure it only has one element

Comment: That doesn't work, but thanks.

Comment: I would also change the find statement if you are searching by id, then see the output of print, e.g.
 collection.find({"_id":1}) SHOULD be enough (unless you DONT want to search by id remember ids are unique so there is no point in adding more stuff to the find).
Then once you got the response, try accessing it:
resp['Values'][0]['Value2'][0]['Value2_2'] ....

Answer (score 0):

By using dot `(.)` notation you can get your expected result.

```
db.collection.find({"Values.Value2.Value2_1" : 100})
```

The above query will select all documents where the `Values` array has `Values2` array and `Values2` has `Values2_1` whose value is equal 100

> Output:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b86bd1172876096c7a9d6cf"),
    "Values" : [ 
        {
            "Value1" : "Article 1",
            "Value2" : [ 
                {
                    "Value2_1" : 100.0,
                    "Value2_2" : 200.0
                }, 
                {
                    "Value2_1" : 15.0,
                    "Value2_2" : 25.0
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

> And if you try to search with `_id` then you don't need to use your
>   second condition because by definition `_id` is always unique.

This following query will also show the same result as above.

```
db.collection.find({"_id" : ObjectId("5b86bd1172876096c7a9d6cf")})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to specifically get only those items from inner array which have fulfill your inner conditions, you can aggregate the query
PS - My 2 cents - I do not know if you require this, as i could not get it that clear from your question, i just thought you may be asking this.

```
db.coll.aggregate([{
            $unwind: '$Values'
        }, {
            $project: {
                'Values_F': {
                    $filter: {
                        input: "$Values.Value2",
                        as: "value2",
                        cond: {
                            $eq: ["$$value2.Value2_1", 1]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }, {
            $project: {
                'Values_F': 1,
                'total': {
                    $size: '$Values_F'
                }
            }
        }, {
            $match: {
                total: {
                    $gte: 1
                }
            }
        }
    ])
```